# Restrict many - many results in SQL join

Tags: sql

The SQL below contains some DDL and a simple query.

The result I am getting is

```
a1|b1|c1  
a1|b2|c3  
a3|b3|c2  
a3|b3|c3  
a3|b3|c4  
a3|b3|c5  
a3|b5|c6  
a3|b5|c7
```

The result I want is

```
a1   |b1   |c1  
a1   |b2   |c3  
a3   |b3   |c2   
null |null |c4  
null |null |c5  
a3   |b5   |c6  
null |null |c7
```

I tried using MAX, MIN, rownums and what not. I am at my wit's end. I am including only the base query I started with and not all the options I tried because they don't work at all. Any help is appreciated!

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

drop table if exists table_A;
drop table if exists table_B;
drop table if exists table_C;

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE table_A(a_Id text PRIMARY KEY, val_a text);
CREATE TABLE table_B(a_Id text, b_Id text, val_b text);
CREATE TABLE table_C(b_Id text, c_Id text, val_c text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO table_A VALUES('a1','va1');
INSERT INTO table_A VALUES('a2','va2');
INSERT INTO table_A VALUES('a3','va3');

INSERT INTO table_B VALUES('a1', 'b1','vb1');
INSERT INTO table_B VALUES('a1', 'b2','vb2');
INSERT INTO table_B VALUES('a3', 'b3','vb31');
INSERT INTO table_B VALUES('a2', 'b4','vb4');
INSERT INTO table_B VALUES('a3', 'b5','vb31');

INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b1', 'c1','vc1');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b3', 'c2','vc2');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b3', 'c3','vc3');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b2', 'c3','vc3');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b3', 'c4','vc2');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b3', 'c5','vc3');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b5', 'c6','vc3');
INSERT INTO table_C VALUES('b5', 'c7','vc3');

COMMIT;

select
a.a_Id, b.b_Id, c.c_Id
from
table_A as a
join
table_B as b
on a.a_Id = b.a_Id
join
table_C as c
on b.b_Id = c.b_Id;
```

Comment: The sample you have is very generic, so it is a bit hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish. I can say that the joins are not going to work given the result set that you are looking for. Take "table_C" with the value c4 for example. When you join to table_B, the value in c's b_id column matches a record in b, and the same for b's record to  table a. So without some where clauses to exclude that you won't get it with simple joins. Not sure if that is much help, but it is hard to determine what your end goal is.

Comment: You've tagged this question "oracle" but the script you posted is not valid Oracle syntax.  Are you sure that you've tagged the question correctly?

Comment: hmm.. Let me put it this way. My query can throw up (key, value) where key is a tuple itself. I want the result set to contain only those tuples whose value has NOT already been chosen. 

So I can have (k1, v1), (k2, v1), (k3, v2), (k4, v1). I want my query to show me (k1, v1), (k2, null), (k3, v2), (k4, null) OR (k1, null), (k2, v1), (k3, v2), (k4, null) OR so on. 

Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: You've removed the oracle tag, but didn't replace it with the database you're actually using. What database is it (it looks like mysql).

Comment: I just copied this off an online sql editor. I am targeting Oracle. But any pointers are fine. I'll worry about conversion later. I want to know how I can approach this problem first.

Comment: Randomly chose an answer because all of them worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work (I have tested it on PostgreSql, should work on Oracle too)

```
SELECT 
  case when row_number = 1 then a_id end as a_id,
  case when row_number = 1 then b_id end as b_id,
  c_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.a_Id, 
    b.b_Id, 
    c.c_Id, 
    row_number() OVER (partition by a.a_id, b.b_id order by c.c_id) as row_number, --for a_id, b_id
    row_number() OVER (partition by c.c_id order by c.c_id) as row_number2         --to avoid c_id duplicates
  FROM
    table_A  a
    join
    table_B  b on a.a_Id = b.a_Id
    join table_C  c on b.b_Id = c.b_Id
  )  innerquery
WHERE 
  row_number2 = 1 --this is to avoid c_id duplicates
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6049b/35)

Answer (score 1):

I'd first recommend that this sounds better to handle in your presentation logic.  However, it is possible to accomplish with SQL alone.

You can take advantage of Oracle's `LAG()` function along with `CASE` to check if the previous row had the same a and b id values.

Here's an example using a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    a.a_Id, b.b_Id, c.c_Id, 
    lag (a.a_Id,1) over (order by a.a_Id, b.b_Id) prev_a_Id,
    lag (b.b_Id,1) over (order by a.a_Id, b.b_Id) prev_b_Id
  from table_A a
    join table_B b
      on a.a_Id = b.a_Id
    join table_C c
      on b.b_Id = c.b_Id
  order by
    a.a_id, b.b_id
  )
select 
  case 
      when prev_a_Id is null or
            prev_a_Id <> a_Id or
            prev_b_Id <> b_Id
      then a_id 
    end new_a_Id,
  case 
      when prev_a_Id is null or
            prev_a_Id = a_Id or
            prev_b_Id = b_Id
      then b_id 
    end new_b_Id, c_Id
from cte;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6049b/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  t1.a_id, t1.b_id, table_c.c_id
from table_c 
left join 
(
  select a_Id, b_Id, c_Id
  from 
  (
    select a.a_Id as a_id, b.b_Id as b_id, c.c_Id as c_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a.a_ID, b.b_id ORDER BY C_ID) as aNum
    from table_A as a
    join table_B as b on a.a_Id = b.a_Id
    join table_C as c on b.b_Id = c.b_Id
  ) t2
  where aNum = 1
) t1 on  table_c.c_id = t1.c_id 
order by table_c.c_id
```

fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6049b/1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think i fully understood that you are trying to achieve, but correct me please if i'm wrong.

First, you use **inner join** to join tables (at least it will be if you use sql server, but should be the same in oracle). That means that for example you will get row from first table only if it has a correspondent row in the second table, And if now rows in first table for corresponding rows in second table, that rows from second table never appear in results.

According to description of result that you want to achieve you need is a **outer join** . Which one exactly **left/right/full outer join** depends on that you are trying to achieve (looks like you need left outer join or full outer join). I'm not quite sure that you exact aim because you explain how your data in this concrete example should looks like not general case.

So please have a look at description of different join types and choose [sql join types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

And also one importation remark: text type is probably last type from the list that i would consider as primary key.

Comment: You are somewhere else... this question is not about the difference between innner and outer joins.  But thanks for guessing.

Comment: Anyway that's not a reason to down vote the answer as question was not clear described.

Comment: I don't think you did it. You just probably highlight the reason why my answer was down voted, despite the fact that it contains some useful things. It's have a deal to make things work the over make it work efficiently.

Comment: Well you were right, in a way, as you can see from my answer c had to be outer joined to the left joined (but limited) query to give the two columns with nulls.